# Dealing with cPickle unavailability

Tags: python, pickle

I have a python program that I would like to run from cmd prompt but every time I try, it keeps giving me an error "NameError: name cPickle is not defined".

I am using python 2.7 and it is the only version I have installed.
I tried to modify the code and make it import pickle instead of import cPickle but it still does not work.

```
import pickle
#import cPickle
import gzip

# Third-party libraries
import numpy as np

def load_data():

    f = gzip.open('../data/mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')
    training_data, validation_data, test_data = cPickle.load(f)
    f.close()
    return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)

def load_data_wrapper():
    tr_d, va_d, te_d = load_data()
    training_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in tr_d[0]]
    training_results = [vectorized_result(y) for y in tr_d[1]]
    training_data = zip(training_inputs, training_results)
    validation_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in va_d[0]]
    validation_data = zip(validation_inputs, va_d[1])
    test_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in te_d[0]]
    test_data = zip(test_inputs, te_d[1])
    return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)

def vectorized_result(j):
    e = np.zeros((10, 1))
    e[j] = 1.0
    return e
```

I changed the line that says

```
training_data, validation_data, test_data = cPickle.load(f)
```

to

```
training_data, validation_data, test_data = pickle.load(f)
```

This did not work and for some reason I cannot find the cPickle package online to install. Can someone please help me figure out a solution to this!

Comment: Since you commented out `import cPickle`, how is it surprising that it isn't defined?

Comment: ...and no, you can't find it online as a separate download: **if** your Python build was compiled correctly, it'll be preinstalled.

Comment: No it wasn't commented out when I tried running it

Comment: (if it's not preinstalled, it wasn't compiled with your Python interpreter, and you simply don't have it).

Comment: "did not work", btw, is not useful. Describe *how* falling back to `pickle` did not work.

Comment: It says no module named cPickle when it tries importing cPickle

Comment: Obviously, yes, because your Python interpreter doesn't have a `cPickle`. You can't fix that without reinstalling Python.

Answer (score 4):

The typical way to deal with uncertainty over whether `cPickle` will be available is to try to load it, and fall back to `pickle` if your Python interpreter doesn't provide this module:

```
try:
    import cPickle as pickle
except ImportError:
    import pickle
```

...after which you can unconditionally use the `pickle` name in either case.

Comment: Yes I tried that and it worked with no errors, but when I try to import this .py file when running another one, I get "UnicodeDecoderError: ascii code can not decodebyte 0x90 in position 614: ordinal not in range (128)"

Comment: @ebz that's an entirely different issue, and has nothing to do with pickling. Try reading through the thousands of UnicodeDecodeError posts on SO to solve it yourself.